# Accidentally ran sudo sh -c command and want to undo

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I have accidentally ran the command

```
sudo sh -c ‘echo “/dev/sda /mnt/usbdrive vfat uid=nobody,gid=nogroup,unmask=0,noatime,rw,user 0 0” >> /etc/fstab'
```

on my Raspberry Pi running Pirate box. Now I want to undo that command. How to I do that?

Comment: Open `/etc/fstab` in the editor of your choice and remove the line you just added. This is not a programming question.

Comment: The line of code you posted is malformed and if that's what you actually executed, then it didn't modify `/etc/fstab` and your terminal is sitting there at `> ` waiting for input.

Answer (score 0):

So the command you ran does nothing but put the content inside the inverted commas into the file located at `/etc/fstab`. To undo that you can open that file and remove that particular line.

1. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
2. Navigate to the last line and press `CTRL+SHIFT+K`.